# jQuery scrollTo focus on element on page

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

I am trying to add a jQuery animation to my click event so that the page scrolls once the element has been clicked.

Here is my code:

```
if (element) {
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, (element.offset().top - 40));
},
500);
}
```

This works in that once the element is opened (it's a box that expands), the page jolts down to the element. The position is fine, but I just it to smoothly animate/scroll to the element.

I think I should be able to add the .animate method somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be:

```
$('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop : $(element).offset().top - 40
}, 900);
```